# Cant configure unit tests correctly with mocha

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js

I am trying to configure mocha on a typescript project, but not working fine
I am using book: Typescript design patterns, chapter 1.

When I run mocha it says:

> Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: out/test/ No
>   test files found

mocha.opts

```
--require ./test/mocha.js
out/test/
```

mocha.js

```
require('chai').should();
```

starter.js

```
describe('some feature', () => {
     it('should pass', () => {
       'foo'.should.not.equal('bar');
     });
     it('should error', () => {
       (() => {
         throw new Error();
       }).should.throw();
}); });
```

[image: project structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, it seems that mocha is trying to look for tests in the `/out` directory. First off, try removing `/out/test` from `mocha.opts` or replacing it with `src/test` to see if that resolves the path issue.

You could also try moving `mocha.js` into the `/src/test` directory, and move the `mocha.opts` to the `/src` directory.

Then, when running mocha, make sure you run from the root of the project (which in this case seems to be `src`)